# What commands to include always in the preamble of a do-file in stata?

Tags: stata

I came across someone's master do file which uses the following commands in the preamble:
[preamble of a sample do file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALEm1.png)

I generally use the following:

```
clear 

capture log close

set more off
```

So I was wondering what  commands should be included always in the preamble.

Also, in relation to this particular example, can anyone please explain what purpose these commands are serving/ what problem I would be facing if I don't include these commands?

Comment: If you generalize this slightly to what commands should go in any Stata program or script, I don't think there is a useful answer beyond "whatever you need to do the job". For example, in my own do-files I often have `clear` but not always. I don't routinely use the other commands, which is not to say that they might not be good  for other people and purposes.  I often set the graph scheme.  That could be irrelevant or unnecessary for others.  As for your last question, do read the help on each command if you don't know what it does.

Comment: thanks, I'll check out the help

Answer (score 0):

There is the `ieboilstart` command from the `ssc install ietoolkit` package that includes some boilerplate code to put at the top of the do-file.